# 3rd-party iOS SDKs?

Tags: ios, sdk

My team and I were just starting to get the evaluation version of AirPlay SDK up and running when their pricing structure changed dramatically, along with changing their name to Marmalade.  I don't think we can afford them at this time since we just purchased a MacBook Pro and still need to pay for the Apple Developer Program and local business licensing fees.

Can you point me in the direction of any other inexpensive 3rd-party SDKs that might provide similar features?  Right now, we don't care so much about compiling for other platforms - I feel like when we are ready for that we will also be ready to license Marmalade or some other SDK.  I am aware of **GameSalad**, but I do come from a programming background and am also aware of **cocos2D** but was hoping for the option of 3D graphics libraries.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and pretty disgusted at the way that Ideaworks are treating developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your 3D requirements, I would recommend cocos2d because there is an additional library in fairly early development called [cocos3d](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/), which as you'd expect, adds 3d capability to cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

May be Shiva3d http://www.stonetrip.com/. 
Perhaps they will change the price because they cooperated with airplay.